# How to parse json info to .cpp?

Tags: c++, json

Im very new to this and thats why Im asking. 
I have this config.cpp file, where i have to parse the volume value into the config.cpp from a json file. Is there an extremely easy way to do this?
You may ask why? Its because I want the volume value to be edited from a json file and not the config.cpp

```cpp
class CfgSoundShaders
{
    //class baseCharacter_SoundShader;
    class LightFire_SoundShader_Fix
    {
        samples[]=
        {

            {
                "FireBarrelFix\sounds\LightFire_fix",
                1
            }
        };
        volume=0.1;         //Default 0.56234133
        range=30;                   //Default 30
    };
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have any builtin features for JSON parsing. You need [a library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Comment: What libary would you recommend me to use? :)

Comment: There's a link in the comment above.

Comment: config + json = poco json configuration? https://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.0/Poco.Util.JSONConfiguration.html

Comment: Yeah okay. Hmm, looks like its way over my ball game. Im not used to program in c++ or using libraries

Comment: While recommendations for libraries are technically off topic for SO, the [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) json parser is really nice.

Comment: Wow, that library's _really_ matured since I last looked at it